# Error for SKScene alloc

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit, skscene

In the SKScene gamescene I alloc the scene but it has an error message with `No visible @interface with 'SKScene' declares the selector alloc.`

I have think this means im not declaring it in my interface?? Corrections plz.

```
     -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

// if play button touched, start transition to next scene
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"play"]) {
    NSLog(@"play pressed");
    SKScene *GameScene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    SKTransition *flip = [SKTransition flipVerticalWithDuration:1.0];
    [self.view presentScene:GameScene transition:flip];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create a variable that is the same name as the class!

```
SKScene *GameScene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
```

This is probably confusing the compiler. Change the variable name of *GameScene to something else and see if that works.